# "org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Undefined attribute for token '<endif>'

Tags: jdbi, jdbi3-core

Method in Dao Interface

```
@RegisterRowMapper(MapMapper.class)
  @SqlQuery(
      "SELECT Table1.tenantId,Table1.sacTenantId, sacLogId,currentStep,status  from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.tenantId = Table2.tenantId where <if(tenantId)>Table1.tenantId = :tenantId and<endif> Table2.status = 'FAILED'")
  List<Map<String, Object>> getTenantFailedJobDetails(@Define("tenantId") @Bind("tenantId") String tenantId);
```

Error trace:

> "level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Servlet.service() for servlet
> [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Error
> rendering SQL template: 'SELECT Table1.tenantId,Table1.sacTenantId,
> sacLogId,currentStep,status from Table1 inner join Table2 on
> Table1.tenantId = Table2.tenantId where <if(tenantId)>Table1.tenantId
> = :tenantId and Table2.status = 'FAILED'' [statement:"null", arguments:{positional:{0:DUMMY-TENANT}, named:{tenantId:DUMMY-TENANT},
> finder:[]}]] with root
> cause","stacktrace":["org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException:
> Undefined attribute for token '' [statement:"null",
> arguments:{positional:{0:DUMMY-TENANT}, named:{tenantId:DUMMY-TENANT},
> finder:[]}]"

What could be wrong with the if condition?

Comment: You forgot to define `<endif>`.

Comment: What needs to be done to define <endif>? I am new to this

Comment: Just put it where your if statement should end.

Comment: I verified the <endif> was at correct place according to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To make if condition in jdbi query work I added annotation @UseStringTemplateEngine of package org.jdbi.v3.stringtemplate4 to the Dao method

If tenandId is not null then where clause will be

Table1.tenantId = :tenantId and Table2.status = 'FAILED'
else where clause will be just

Table2.status = 'FAILED'
One more information to add, for the else part annotation @AllowUnusedBindings package org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.customizer is required

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you posted is stringtemplate4, so you need to use the stringtemplate 4 engine (which you select with the annotation that you posted). Otherwise you end up with the default engine which does support only very simply substitutions (and not st4 syntax).